# How can I transform a Play application to an Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

In the play documentation I found the link (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/ide) describing how to convert a Play project into a Eclipse project.

I followed the following steps but Play doesn't accept the newly created application.

- Why Play doesn't accept my application?

I am using:

- Scala: Scala code runner version 2.9.2 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL
- Play 2.2.1

**I create a play application**

```
/play-2.2.1$ ./play new hello
       _
 _ __ | | __ _ _  _
| '_ \| |/ _' | || |
|  __/|_|\____|\__ /
|_|            |__/

play 2.2.1 built with Scala 2.10.2 (running Java 1.7.0_40), http://www.playframework.com

The new application will be created in /home/<user>/programming/play-2.2.1/hello
What is the application name? [hello]
> 

Which template do you want to use for this new application? 

  1             - Create a simple Scala application
  2             - Create a simple Java application

> 1
OK, application hello is created.

Have fun!
```

**However, play does not accept hello as an application**

```
~/programming/play-2.2.1$ ./play eclipsify hello
       _
 _ __ | | __ _ _  _
| '_ \| |/ _' | || |
|  __/|_|\____|\__ /
|_|            |__/

play 2.2.1 built with Scala 2.10.2 (running Java 1.7.0_40), http://www.playframework.com

This is not a play application!

Use `play new` to create a new Play application in the current directory,
or go to an existing application and launch the development console using `play`.

You can also browse the complete documentation at http://www.playframework.com.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the documentation for a previous version of Play. The documentation for your version is http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/IDE.

The command you need to use is `eclipse`. It changed sometime between 2.0 and 2.1.

There is also a tutorial on the [Scala IDE website](http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/play/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

I realized that you need to use another command than provided in the documentation - I used the command `eclipse` and **not** `eclipsify`.

```
>>> cd <my_application>
>>> ../play eclipse <my_application>
```

The commands above worked for me.